# Main method not found error Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run the simple word count program below in Eclipse and i am getting a error .I have checked my configurations in Run As and they are correct

```
Error: Main method not found in class wordcount.WordCount, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Here is the program

package wordcount;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// This program does word-counting on the text of Moby Dick.
public class WordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    HashMap map = new HashMap();  // word --> # of occurrences

    // read each word from the file
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("mobydick.txt"));
    while (in.hasNext()) {
      String word = in.next();

      if(map.containsKey(word)) {
        // if we have already seen this word before,
        // increment its count by one
        Integer count = (Integer)map.get(word);
        map.put(word, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
      } else {
        // we haven't seen this word, so add it with count of 1
        map.put(word, new Integer(1));
      }
    }

    // now print out every word in the book, along with its count,
    // in alphabetical order
    ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(arraylist);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
      String key = (String)arraylist.get(i);
      Integer count = (Integer)map.get(key);
      System.out.println(key + " --> " + count);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: working fine for me ... check your build path

Comment: why does your main method throw an Exception? Where do you think you're throwing it to? your main method is the last chance of handling it.
your code 'll run perfectly well. are you sure you saved the code?

Comment: @chenchuk how to check the build path?

Comment: @Stultuske i had not saved the code .Thanks for pointing it out.If you answer the questions i will select it

Comment: The first line of the console output should be the full Java startup command line - how your application was started. Add it to your question, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why does your main method throw an Exception? Where do you think you're throwing it to? your main method is the last chance of handling it.

Your code 'll run perfectly well. Are you sure you saved the code? If not, the code isn't compiled and thus the method can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

When you press RUN button in your IDE, it tries to run last used project/class, so it may not be this class started after clicking on RUN. P.S. Sorry for bad english.